# React - redirecting to full url and not relative url

Tags: reactjs, django, forms

Good afternoon,

I built a django form for my thesis work that I intend to interviewees. To make it more appealing and increase the number of answers (I hope! :)) I built a page using a tutorial on react. It looks very nice. The problem is that building my form with react looks like a nightmare.

So I would like to have a button on my react page that once clicked redirect to my django html page with the form. I looked online but none of the topics I found did the trick ([React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link), [react-router redirect to a different domain url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095759/react-router-redirect-to-a-different-domain-url), [react button onClick redirect page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644976/react-button-onclick-redirect-page)).

I would like to have something like:

```
<NavBtnLink to="http://127.0.0.1:8000/doctor/7f06cb1c-d68e-459e-9d07-ce4d52d2b50b/survey/%22%3ETake the survey</NavBtnLink>
```

but that tries to redirect me to:

`http://localhost:3000/http://127.0.0.1:8000/doctor/7f06cb1c-d68e-459e-9d07-ce4d52d2b50b/survey/`

instead of:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/doctor/7f06cb1c-d68e-459e-9d07-ce4d52d2b50b/survey/`

Any idea of things I could try (on top of what is suggested in the mentionned topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in this case , you are not needing the power of react router .

Keep it simple and only use html **a** tag

```
 <a href="your link here">Take the survey</a>
```

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm. Completely forgot to try that. I tried Link but not that one. Thank you.