# select onchange redirect vs button list href for loading the page

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

I want to build a professional site which includes a filter for loading the content.I am confused to go with select or button dropwdown list for reloadng the page. I am using pug(template) more or like html only. Which one is suitable select or button dropdown

```html
   <select name="selectData" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
    <option value="/api1"> Mon </option>
    <option value="/api2"> Tue </option>
    <option value="/api3"> Wed </option>
  </select>


  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span class="caret"> selectedvalue </span>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="/api1">Mon</a></li>
     <li><a href="/api2">Tue</a></li>
     <li><a href="/api3">Wed</a></li>
  </ul>
  </button>
```

Comment: The  button code simply places HTML elements literally on a clickable button. That UX doesn't make any sense. For best accessibility, you should have an `<ul>` that can have its display turned on or off with CSS and not go with either of your suggestions.

Comment: If you are asking whether to go with anchor or js location change, then anchor tags are better for a variety of [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667416/window-location-href-vs-clicking-on-an-anchor)

Comment: @ScottMarcus can u brief the solution

Comment: Just use an unordered list with hyperlinks in the list items. Then show or hid the list (if that's what you want to do) through the clicking of some other item.